# Values of an array not getting displayed inside a particular div

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am receiving an array of values that loop like this

This array keeps on changing, based on previous conditions. Values inside this array should get displayed inside a div in a particular format, to do this i wrote the following code,

But the data is not getting displayed inside the div.
I want that whenever the array changes, values in it should get re-rendered inside the div
Can anyone please tell how to do it

```js
var children = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "name-1",
    age: "6",
    price: "100"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "name-2",
    age: "9",
    price: "100"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "name-3",
    age: "9",
    price: "100"
  }
]



var z = children.forEach((element) => {
  return res = '<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">' +
    ' <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">' +
    '<div>' + element.name + '(age ' + element.age + ')' + '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">' +
    '<div>' + element.price + '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>'
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Why did you tag with jquery?

Comment: Split html from javascript.

Comment: Longer term tip: If you want to bind the data to your display (i.e. such that it updates if the data changes) this would be a very good time to move away from writing imperative code to a reactive framework such as React, Vue etc.

Comment: could you change z to a function?  `function z() {`...`}` and `document`...`=z();`

Comment: @iAmOren that is not how that works. They need a map and `z.join("")`

Comment: Remove `res = ` from the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.forEach` is a void function so doesn't return nothing so has no sense returning an assignation

Try this:

```
<div id="result"></div>

var z = "";
children.forEach((element) => {
    z += '<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">' +
            ' <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">' +
                '<div>' + element.name +'(age ' + element.age + ')' + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">' +
                '<div>' + element.price + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>'
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z;
```

Comment: It's always better to *explain* your answer rather than just provide code. That way, the OP stands more chance of understanding your solution. Moreover, this doesn't deal with the OP's concern for the display to update when the source data changes.

Comment: @Mitya You're true. Edited the answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` has no return types, so return inside a `forEach` is pointless instead use something like `map` as shown below

```
var z = children.map((element) => {
        return res = '<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">' +
                ' <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">' +
                    '<div>' + element.name +'(age ' + element.age + ')' + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">' +
                    '<div>' + element.price + '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    });
```

z here will be an array of elements, and if you want you can use reduce further to combine all the elements to one single string complied with required values as below

```
z = z.reduce(acc=>acc+=acc);
```

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var z = arr.map(val => (`<p>${val}</p>`))

document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = z.reduce((acc, val) => acc += val, '');
```

```html
<div id="someId"></div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =z.join("")` would be simpler

Comment: No need for `res=` there

Comment: @mplungjan accepted... feel free to edit and add your own version to it

Comment: Why do you reduce the array - Just use z.join("") !

Answer (score 0):

forEach is an Array function and doesn't return anything, You could try like this:

```
var children = [
  {id: 1, name: "name-1", age: "6", price: "100"},
  {id: 2, name: "name-2", age: "9", price: "100"},
  {id: 3, name: "name-3", age: "9", price: "100"}
]
    
var z = '';

children.forEach((element) => {
  z += '<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">' +
          ' <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">' +
              '<div>' + element.name +'(age ' + element.age + ')' + '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">' +
              '<div>' + element.price + '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
      '</div>'
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible code:

```
function z() {
  var res="";
  for(var element of children) {
    res += '<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">' +
           '  <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">' +
           '    <div>' + element.name +'(age ' + element.age + ')' + '</div>' +
           '  </div>' +
           '  <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">' +
           '    <div>' + element.price + '</div>' +
           '  </div>' +
           '</div>'
  }
  return res;
}
```

Called by:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = z();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems all who answer gets it slightly wrong, here is what you need

1. use map
2. return rendered html
3. insert the joined result

```js
const children = [
  {id: 1, name: "name-1", age: "6", price: "100"},
  {id: 2, name: "name-2", age: "9", price: "100"},
  {id: 3, name: "name-3", age: "9", price: "100"}
];

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = children.map(
  element => `<div class="row" style="color: #888888; font-size:16px;">
  <div class="col-md-8" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <div>${element.name} (age ${element.age})</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: right;">
    <div>${element.price}</div>
  </div>
</div>`).join("");
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```